# OroCommerce Custom Configurable Product Issue

Tags: product, message-queue, configurable-product, orocommerce

I created some new attributes and product family for the configurable products and connected the attributes with the new product family in the Admin UI. Simple products created with the new product family. 
After creating simple products, I created the configurable product with the new product family. In frontend I can see the configurable product but cannot see the product variants. Like there is no size and color variants' dropdown which I've created for the new product family, the new attributes. Message consumer working and I reindexed the website. 
What is the reason and solution for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you followed all the steps according to the official documentation on [how to create a configurable product in OroCommerce](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/products/products/create-complex/#products-products-create-config-product).

Here are the most common issues:

- Products are not enabled. In this case, make sure they are enabled by checking [the variants grid](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/products/products/manage/view/#product-variants).
- You have a different Unit Of Quantity in configurable and simple products. In this case change product unit codes to be the same everywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I did control all of your mentions. Products enabled in the variants grid and both configurable and simple product has the same unit of quantity. My new attributes are size, color and gender so I gave a value for these attributes of the simple product. For example size:36, color:Black and gender:Men so what can i do on this point. 100% I can see the products variants in the variants grid. Is there any another ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: You may also have a matrix ordering form configured instead of the dropdown for the product view page. See the documentation to find how to change it https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/configuration/commerce/product/global-configurable-products/#config-guide-landing-commerce-products-configurable-products